# invalid option value exception using boost program-options

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application using boost v1.45.0 program-options.

I would like to be able to parse a command-line option that looks like this: `foo.exe -x 1,2, 4-7` such that it produces a `std::vector< int >` with the values [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]. So, I've written a custom validator:

```
typedef std::vector< int > IDList;

void validate( boost::any& v, const std::vector< std::string >& tokens, IDList*, int )
{
    // Never gets here
}

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
    IDList test_case_ids;

    po::options_description desc( "Foo options" );
    desc.add_options()
        ("id,x", po::value< IDList >(), "Specify a single ID or a range of IDs as shown in the following command line: foo.exe -x10,12, 15-20")
    ;

    po::variables_map vm;

    try
    {
        po::store( po::parse_command_line( argc, argv, desc ), vm );
        po::notify( vm );
    }
    catch( const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << desc << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But, I never get to my custom validator code. I always get an exception in `parse_command_line` with the message: `in option 'id': invalid option value`.

What do I need to do to make this work as desired?

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: What is the command line that you give it when you are running?

Comment: BTW -- Are you compiling using UNICODE... in which case you need to use the wstring versions of the library operations.

Comment: @Dennis - the command line is `foo.exe -x 1,2, 4-7`. Yes, I'm compiling with the UNICODE flag. Changing to `std::wstring` does not change the result. I get the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typedef `std::vector<int>` as a `boost::program_options::value_semantic` does not work the way you desire because a `vector` has a [special meaning](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2217606) to the program options library:

> The library provides special support
>   for vectors -- it will be possible to
>   specify the option several times, and
>   all specified values will be collected
>   in one vector.

which means a description like so

```
typedef std::vector< int > IDList;
po::options_description desc( "Foo options" );
desc.add_options()
    ("id,x", po::value< IDList >(), "list of IDs")
;
```

is coalesced into a single `std::vector<int>` given the following command line

```
a.out --id 1 --id 2 --id 3 --id 4
```

the result would be a `std::vector` with four elements. You need to define a specific type to use the custom validator, `struct IDList` is the [correct approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120303/invalid-option-value-exception-using-boost-program-options/5121928#5121928).

Comment: Are you saying that the type(def) IDList is 'magic' in this case? Ie it must be named IDList not something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing your own function to parse the command line options:

[See here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/program_options/howto.html#id2219690)

You write your own parser function, e.g. reg_foo, and use it as follows:

```
variables_map vm;
store(command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).extra_parser(reg_foo)
          .run(), vm);
```

See also the example code distributed with boost, in example/custom_syntax.cpp

Comment: I suppose I could do that, but I only need the custom parser for the `-x` option. I thought that was what the custom validator was for?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the definition of `IDList`. If I change the definition to match the `magic_number` type used in the `regex.cpp` sample, it works.

```
struct IDList
{
public:
    std::vector< int > ids_;
    IDList( std::vector< int > ids ) : ids_( ids ) {}
};
```

I haven't investigated why a `typedef` is a problem for the framework, but this works.

-PaulH

Comment: What's the point of SO letting me post an answer if I can't accept it for 2 days?

Comment: to encourage other answers, you won't gain rep by answering your own question.

Comment: @Sam - I was unclear. I meant, "Why let me post an answer at all if I can't mark it as the answer for 2 days?".